# Finding the top 3 people who ate the max number of pizzas

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with names, pizzas, pizzerias and prices. I need to find the top 3 people who ate the max numbers of pizzas which is basically one of every type of pizza

Table name is Eats

Amy pepperoni

Amy mushroom

Ben pepperoni

Ben cheese

Cal supreme

Dan pepperoni

Dan cheese

Dan sausage

Dan supreme

Dan mushroom

Eli supreme

Eli cheese

Fay mushroom

Gus mushroom

Gus supreme

Gus cheese

Hil supreme

Hil cheese

Ian supreme

Ian pepperoni

The code I have so far

SELECT DISTINCT name, (count(pizza))

from eats

order by count(pizza) DESC

Limit 3

Thank you in advance.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to find the top 3 people who ate the max numbers of pizzas which is basically one of every type of pizza

I don't get how these two ideas are related.

You basically want:

```
select name, count(*) as num_eats,
       count(distinct pizza) as num_pizzas
from t
group by name
order by num_pizzas desc
limit 3;
```

I'm not sure if you want `num_eats desc` or `num_pizzas desc` in the `order by`.